# How to use Identity in a empty application with inheritance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, identity

I have an application where I am trying to use inheritance and identity to control it.

I have a class People, where Client and Chef inherit the characteristics of this people.

I created an empty MVC application, and would like to use Identity. I researched last week on how to implement Identity in an empty application and the examples are always found to create a MVC Individual Account and use it as a base. From this I'm having too much trouble, could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for here, but the way Identity works is that you create a class that inherits from `IdentityUser` and that becomes your user object for the application:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

You can extend this class with whatever properties you would like stored for a user in your application. If Client and Chef are supposed to be users of the system (you can login as a client/chef), then they should inherit from your user entity, `ApplicationUser` here.

```
public class Client : ApplicationUser
{
}

public class Chef : ApplicationUser
{
}
```

Again, you can extend those classes however you like to store additional information as necessary. However, bear in mind that the inheritance hierarchy will be persisted using STI (single table inheritance). In other words, all the properties from the user entity and all subclasses of that user entity will all be on the same table. A discriminator column will be added to inform Entity Framework what class it should instantiate with the data from each row. In practical terms, this only means that you can't have non-nullable properties on subclasses. For example, if `Chef` had a property like `public string CulinarySchool { get; set; }`, you could not make this required on the entity, as `Client` does not have this property and therefore could not satisfy the requirement. This only affects your entity classes, though. You can still create a view model where you require this property for the purposes of a form.

As for your `People` class, it depends on what you want to do with this. C# does not support multiple inheritance so your only options are to either replace the `People` class with `ApplicationUser`, by basically just moving all its properties over, or you can make `People` a subclass of `ApplicationUser`, and then have `Client` and `Chef` inherit from it as they do now:

```
public class People : ApplicationUser
{
}

public class Client : People
{
}

public class Chef : People
{
}
```

If there should never actually be an instance of `People`, you can make it abstract.

Comment: Thank you Chris Pratt! It's  exactly what i'm looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity)? This is fairly new.

[Cutting Edge - A first look at ASP.NET Identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605872.aspx)